# Javascript method execution order

Tags: javascript, yeoman

While reading yeoman generator documentation (http://yeoman.io/generators.html#writing-your-first-generator), I came across following line.

***Starting from the top, every method you place on the BlogGenerator.prototype will be invoked in the order you've written them.***

How does yeoman execute methods in the same order?

Comment: Out of context, that line makes basically no sense. Looking at the documentation for context, that line is probably wrong. They probably meant "evaluated," not "invoked." (Since they're function expressions, the function is evaluated -- **not** invoked -- in the step-by-step order of the code and the resulting `Function` object is assigned to the property on the `prototype`.)

Comment: JavaScript is a procedural scripting language. It's *always* executed in the order it's written - top-down. Other than that, I have no clue what you're asking.

Comment: @crowder.. i thought so.. 'invoked' is wrong. and if it means evaluated then the line is not required. its understood that evaluation will follow the order.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it's as easy as...

```
var methods = Object.keys(Object.getPrototypeOf(this));
```

Here's the [Github link](https://github.com/yeoman/generator/blob/master/lib/base.js#L251). And yes, they're invoked, not evaluated:

```
/*
 * Runs the generator, executing top-level methods in the order they
 * were defined.
 */
// ...
async.series(methods.map(resolve), runHooks);
```

Technically that might end up in a trouble if one defines a property with a numeric name. For example:

```
var Foo = function() {};
Foo.prototype.bar  = function() { console.log('I am bar'); };
Foo.prototype[123] = function() { console.log('I am 123'); };

var foo = new Foo(); 
var methods = Object.keys(Object.getPrototypeOf(foo)); // ['123', 'bar']
methods.map(function(fn) { foo[fn]() }); 
// I am 123
// I am bar
```

But I assume those cases are considered non-existant. For all the others, it looks like V8 is honoring the properties' insertion order - otherwise the code given won't function as expected, obviously.

Comment: agreed. but how can that ensure the order of keys? the keys can come in any order.

Comment: Well, you're expected not to define functions with numeric names, I suppose. Apart from those, Node.js implementation is (I assume) expected to honor the insertion order.

Comment: @raina77ow: Node.js is NOT expected to honor insertion order. Specifically ECMAscript specification states that object keys have no order. Any code depending on the order of a specific implementation at a specific version should be considered buggy since future versions of Node.js is not guaranteed to honor insertion order.

Comment: @slebetman Have you visited the links I've given? The code in the beginning is taken directly from Yeoman generator master branch - and it's working the way it's described in the documentation (which was the original question) _because_ V8 orders the properties the way it does _NOW_. Now tell me, what exactly should be changed in my comment/answer? That the code shown is buggy? That's too high claim for my taste.

Comment: Yep, this answer is correct, unfortunately. The bad is with the implementation style used by Yeoman (i.e. expectation of honouring order), not raina77ow. I hope this gets addressed in the future. But one more thing to note- method names that start with underscore will not get invoked, so you CAN implement 'private' methods should you need your own utility methods etc.

Comment: Object properties [have order now](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-ownpropertykeys), so the implementation is no longer relying on undocumented behavior.